# How to draw an outline on the screen around a given rectangle?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, core-graphics

My goal is to draw an outline around another application's window. Similar to how Microsoft Teams draws an outline during desktop sharing.

For example, an outline around Safari's window like shown in this image.

[image: Something like this]

Using macOS's Quartz Window Services & accessibility APIs I was able to get the coordinates of Safari (x, y, width, height) and I'm subscribed to events that happen to the window like resizing or if the window changes its position.

```c
// How I get window coordinates

- (CGRect)selectedAppCoordinates:(long)windowId {
  NSLog(@"selectedAppCoordinates - IN");
  CGRect rect;
  CGWindowID windowid[1];
  windowid[0] = windowId;
  CFArrayRef windowArray =
      CFArrayCreate(nullptr, (const void **)windowid, 1, nullptr);
  CFArrayRef windowsdescription =
      CGWindowListCreateDescriptionFromArray(windowArray);
  CFDictionaryRef windowdescription = (CFDictionaryRef)CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(
      (CFArrayRef)windowsdescription, 0);
  if (CFDictionaryContainsKey(windowdescription, kCGWindowBounds)) {
    CFDictionaryRef bounds = (CFDictionaryRef)CFDictionaryGetValue(
        windowdescription, kCGWindowBounds);
    if (bounds) {
      if (CGRectMakeWithDictionaryRepresentation(bounds, &rect)) {

        NSLog(@"x: %f, y: %f, width: %f, height: %f", rect.origin.x,
              rect.origin.y, rect.size.width, rect.size.height);
      }
    }
  }
  CFRelease(windowArray);
  NSLog(@"selectedAppCoordinates - OUT");

  return rect;
}
```

The problem for me is drawing the outline. I have little experience with native macOS development and I would appreciate any help.

How should I draw this outline, update and hide it when needed?

Comment: I don't have time to write up a proper answer now, so I'll answer in a comment.  The simple way to do this, as far as I know, is to make a borderless window with a transparent background, and then draw a rectangle in red around the edge of that window.  Make your window float above other windows, and make it match the target window in its size and location (plus the appropriate margin).  If you keep things synced up, it will look like a border drawn around the target window.  Or four non-transparent borderless windows, one for each edge, if you prefer.

Comment: Thank you @bhaller. I'm trying to code something similar to what you suggested but I'm struggling in creating/updating/hiding the outline window because I'm not familiar at all with macOS development. I'm just trying to do this side feature for an Electron.js application where I need to go native. I was hoping a generous stranger would enlighten me with an actual code demonstration of how to do this.

Comment: It's not exactly what you want, but this code might get you started: https://github.com/bhaller/Jiggler/blob/master/JigglerOverlayWindow.m .  That creates a borderless window with a view inside it.  The view derives from NSImageView, which you won't want; just use your own NSView, and in its drawRect: method use NSFrameRect() to frame the bounds of the view, which you get from [self bounds], in a color like [NSColor redColor].  Sorry; if you remain stuck after some effort, post a question here and I'll try to help, but I don't have time to write up a complete answer right now.

Comment: Thanks. I'll give this a try.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the suggestions previously given by bhaller, the following demo uses a second underlay window containing a color filled view and slightly larger than the main window so that a rim of it is visible.  The underlay window is tied to the main window through the window delegate to synchronously change position/size and may be shown or hidden.  The demo may be run in Xcode by replacing the main file with the code below and additionally deleting the AppDelegate files supplied by Apple (to avoid duplicate symbols errors):

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface CustomView : NSView
@end

@implementation CustomView
 
- (id)initWithFrame:(NSRect)frameRect{
 if ((self = [super initWithFrame:frameRect]) != nil) {
 // Add initialization code here
 }
 return self;
}
 
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)rect {
 // ****** Background ***** //
 [[NSColor redColor] set];
 [NSBezierPath fillRect:rect];
}
 
 // ----- Use this if you want 0,0 (origin) to be top, left ---- //
 // ----- Otherwise origin will be at bottom, left (Unflipped) ----- //
 -(BOOL)isFlipped
 {
 return YES;
 }
@end

@interface WindowDelegate : NSObject <NSWindowDelegate>
 @property(strong) NSWindow *underlayWnd;
@end

@implementation WindowDelegate
 
- (void)windowDidResize:(NSNotification *)notification {
NSRect frameR = NSMakeRect([notification.object frame].origin.x - 10, [notification.object frame].origin.y - 10, [notification.object frame].size.width + 20, [notification.object frame].size.height + 20);
[_underlayWnd setFrame:frameR display:YES];
}
 
- (void)windowDidEndLiveResize:(NSNotification *)notification {
 NSRect frameR = NSMakeRect([notification.object frame].origin.x - 10, [notification.object frame].origin.y - 10, [notification.object frame].size.width + 20, [notification.object frame].size.height + 20);
[_underlayWnd setFrame:frameR display:YES];
}
 
- (void)windowDidMove:(NSNotification *)notification {
 NSRect frameR = NSMakeRect([notification.object frame].origin.x - 10, [notification.object frame].origin.y - 10, [notification.object frame].size.width + 20, [notification.object frame].size.height + 20);
 [_underlayWnd setFrame:frameR display:YES];
}
 
- (void)windowDidMiniaturize:(NSNotification *)notification {
NSRect frameR = NSMakeRect([notification.object frame].origin.x - 10, [notification.object frame].origin.y - 10, [notification.object frame].size.width + 20, [notification.object frame].size.height + 20);
 [_underlayWnd setFrame:frameR display:YES];
}
  
@end
 
@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate>
{
 NSWindow *window;
 NSWindow *underlayWnd;
 WindowDelegate *windowDelegate;
 CustomView *view;
}
- (void) myShowAction;
- (void) myHideAction;
- (void) buildMenu;
- (void) buildWindow;
@end

@implementation AppDelegate

-(void) myHideAction {
 [underlayWnd orderOut:nil];
 }

-(void) myShowAction {
 [underlayWnd orderFront:nil];
 [window makeKeyAndOrderFront: nil];
}

- (void) buildMenu {
NSMenu *menubar = [NSMenu new];
NSMenuItem *menuBarItem = [NSMenuItem new];
[menubar addItem:menuBarItem];
[NSApp setMainMenu:menubar];
NSMenu *appMenu = [NSMenu new];
NSMenuItem *quitMenuItem = [[NSMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Quit"
action:@selector(terminate:) keyEquivalent:@"q"];
[appMenu addItem:quitMenuItem];
[menuBarItem setSubmenu:appMenu];
}

- (void) buildWindow {

windowDelegate = [[WindowDelegate alloc]init];

#define _wndW  700
#define _wndH  550

window = [[NSWindow alloc] initWithContentRect: NSMakeRect( 0, 0, _wndW, _wndH )
styleMask: NSWindowStyleMaskTitled | NSWindowStyleMaskMiniaturizable | NSWindowStyleMaskClosable | NSWindowStyleMaskResizable
backing: NSBackingStoreBuffered defer: NO];

[window center];
[window setTitle: @"Test window"];
[window setDelegate: windowDelegate];
[window makeKeyAndOrderFront: nil];

NSRect frameR = NSMakeRect([window frame].origin.x - 10, [window frame].origin.y - 10, [window frame].size.width + 20, [window frame].size.height + 20);
underlayWnd = [[NSWindow alloc] initWithContentRect:frameR styleMask: NSWindowStyleMaskBorderless backing: NSBackingStoreBuffered defer: NO];
[underlayWnd setIgnoresMouseEvents:true];
[underlayWnd orderWindow:NSWindowBelow relativeTo:0];

// **** Custom View **** //
view = [[CustomView alloc]initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(0,0,frameR.size.width, frameR.size.height)];
[view setAutoresizingMask: NSViewWidthSizable | NSViewHeightSizable ];
[[underlayWnd contentView] addSubview:view]
[windowDelegate setUnderlayWnd:underlayWnd];

// **** Hide Button **** //
NSButton *hideBtn =[[NSButton alloc]initWithFrame:NSMakeRect( 30, 30, 165, 30 )];
[hideBtn setBezelStyle:NSBezelStyleRounded ];
[hideBtn setTitle: @"Hide underlay window"];
[hideBtn setAction: @selector (myHideAction)];
[[window contentView] addSubview: hideBtn];

// **** Show Button **** //
NSButton *showBtn =[[NSButton alloc]initWithFrame:NSMakeRect( 210, 30, 165, 30 )];
[showBtn setBezelStyle:NSBezelStyleRounded ];
[showBtn setTitle: @"Show underlay window"];
[showBtn setAction: @selector (myShowAction)];
[[window contentView] addSubview: showBtn];

// **** Quit btn **** //
NSButton *quitBtn = [[NSButton alloc]initWithFrame:NSMakeRect( _wndW - 50, 5, 40, 40 )];
[quitBtn setBezelStyle:NSBezelStyleCircular ];
[quitBtn setTitle: @"Q" ];
[quitBtn setAutoresizingMask: NSViewMinXMargin];
[quitBtn setAction:@selector(terminate:)];
[[window contentView] addSubview: quitBtn];
}

- (void) applicationWillFinishLaunching: (NSNotification *)notification
{
[self buildMenu];
[self buildWindow];
}

- (void) applicationDidFinishLaunching: (NSNotification *)notification
{
}
@end

int main (){
NSApplication *application = [NSApplication sharedApplication];
AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[AppDelegate alloc] init];
[application setDelegate:appDelegate];
[application run];
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm currently digesting this information and trying to integrate it into my project.